Ubuntu 24.04 NVIDIA monitor doesn't connect through usb-c to hdmi adapter
I have HP Victus 16-d0377ng (https://support.hp.com/ch-de/document/c08081168) laptop and 2 external monitors.
Now I use 2 monitors (built in and hdmi) but I have type-c to hdmi adapter that works perfectly fine on other laptop, but not with mine (I have DisplayPort 1.4 compatibility). Monitor worked before through this adapter (without extra configuration), but I'm not really sure why it stopped.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
Release:    24.04
Codename:   noble

xrandr output
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 355mm x 200mm
   1920x1080    144.00*+ 144.00    60.03  
   1680x1050    144.00  
   1400x1050    144.00  
   1600x900     144.00  
   1280x1024    144.00  
   1400x900     144.00  
   1280x960     144.00  
   1440x810     144.00  
   1368x768     144.00  
   1280x800     144.00  
   1152x864     144.00  
   1280x720     144.00  
   1024x768     144.00  
   1024x768i    144.00  
   960x720      144.00  
   928x696      144.00  
   896x672      144.00  
   1024x576     144.00  
   960x600      144.00  
   832x624      144.00  
   960x540      144.00  
   800x600      144.00  
   840x525      144.00  
   864x486      144.00  
   700x525      144.00  
   800x450      144.00  
   640x512      144.00  
   700x450      144.00  
   640x480      144.00  
   720x405      144.00  
   720x400      144.00  
   684x384      144.00  
   640x400      144.00  
   576x432      144.00  
   640x360      144.00  
   640x350      144.00  
   512x384      144.00  
   512x384i     144.00  
   512x288      144.00  
   416x312      144.00  
   480x270      144.00  
   400x300      144.00  
   432x243      144.00  
   320x240      144.00  
   360x202      144.00  
   360x200      144.00  
   320x200      144.00  
   320x180      144.00  
   320x175      144.00  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1-0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 476mm x 268mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    72.19    60.32    56.25  
   640x480       75.00    59.94

lshw output
*-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GA107M [GeForce RTX 3050 Ti Mobile]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=nvidia latency=0 mode=1920x1080 visual=truecolor xres=1920 yres=1080
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:610-60f irq:198 memory:54000000-54ffffff memory:6000000000-60ffffffff memory:6100000000-6101ffffff ioport:4000(size=128) memory:55000000-5507ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: TigerLake-H GT1 [UHD Graphics]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 resolution=1920,1080
       resources: iomemory:610-60f iomemory:400-3ff irq:197 memory:6104000000-6104ffffff memory:4000000000-400fffffff ioport:5000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff memory:4010000000-4016ffffff memory:4020000000-40ffffffff

lspci -vvv -s 01:00.0 output
0000:01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GA107M [GeForce RTX 3050 Ti Mobile] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    DeviceName: NVIDIA Graphics Device
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company GA107M [GeForce RTX 3050 Ti Mobile]
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 198
    IOMMU group: 14
    Region 0: Memory at 54000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Region 1: Memory at 6000000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=4G]
    Region 3: Memory at 6100000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
    Region 5: I/O ports at 4000 [size=128]
    Expansion ROM at 55000000 [virtual] [disabled] [size=512K]
    Capabilities: [60] Power Management version 3
        Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0+,D1-,D2-,D3hot+,D3cold-)
        Status: D0 NoSoftRst+ PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
    Capabilities: [68] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Address: 00000000fee009b8  Data: 0000
    Capabilities: [78] Express (v2) Legacy Endpoint, MSI 00
        DevCap: MaxPayload 256 bytes, PhantFunc 0, Latency L0s unlimited, L1 <64us
            ExtTag+ AttnBtn- AttnInd- PwrInd- RBE+ FLReset+
        DevCtl: CorrErr- NonFatalErr- FatalErr- UnsupReq-
            RlxdOrd+ ExtTag+ PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop+ FLReset-
            MaxPayload 256 bytes, MaxReadReq 512 bytes
        DevSta: CorrErr- NonFatalErr- FatalErr- UnsupReq- AuxPwr- TransPend+
        LnkCap: Port #0, Speed 16GT/s, Width x16, ASPM L0s L1, Exit Latency L0s <512ns, L1 <16us
            ClockPM+ Surprise- LLActRep- BwNot- ASPMOptComp+
        LnkCtl: ASPM Disabled; RCB 64 bytes, Disabled- CommClk+
            ExtSynch- ClockPM+ AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
        LnkSta: Speed 2.5GT/s (downgraded), Width x8 (downgraded)
            TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
        DevCap2: Completion Timeout: Range AB, TimeoutDis+ NROPrPrP- LTR+
             10BitTagComp+ 10BitTagReq+ OBFF Via message, ExtFmt- EETLPPrefix-
             EmergencyPowerReduction Not Supported, EmergencyPowerReductionInit-
             FRS-
             AtomicOpsCap: 32bit- 64bit- 128bitCAS-
        DevCtl2: Completion Timeout: 50us to 50ms, TimeoutDis- LTR+ 10BitTagReq- OBFF Disabled,
             AtomicOpsCtl: ReqEn-
        LnkCap2: Supported Link Speeds: 2.5-16GT/s, Crosslink- Retimer+ 2Retimers+ DRS-
        LnkCtl2: Target Link Speed: 16GT/s, EnterCompliance- SpeedDis-
             Transmit Margin: Normal Operating Range, EnterModifiedCompliance- ComplianceSOS-
             Compliance Preset/De-emphasis: -6dB de-emphasis, 0dB preshoot
        LnkSta2: Current De-emphasis Level: -6dB, EqualizationComplete+ EqualizationPhase1+
             EqualizationPhase2+ EqualizationPhase3+ LinkEqualizationRequest-
             Retimer- 2Retimers- CrosslinkRes: unsupported
    Capabilities: [b4] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
    Capabilities: [100 v1] Virtual Channel
        Caps:   LPEVC=0 RefClk=100ns PATEntryBits=1
        Arb:    Fixed- WRR32- WRR64- WRR128-
        Ctrl:   ArbSelect=Fixed
        Status: InProgress-
        VC0:    Caps:   PATOffset=00 MaxTimeSlots=1 RejSnoopTrans-
            Arb:    Fixed- WRR32- WRR64- WRR128- TWRR128- WRR256-
            Ctrl:   Enable+ ID=0 ArbSelect=Fixed TC/VC=01
            Status: NegoPending- InProgress-
    Capabilities: [250 v1] Latency Tolerance Reporting
        Max snoop latency: 34326183936ns
        Max no snoop latency: 34326183936ns
    Capabilities: [258 v1] L1 PM Substates
        L1SubCap: PCI-PM_L1.2+ PCI-PM_L1.1+ ASPM_L1.2+ ASPM_L1.1+ L1_PM_Substates+
              PortCommonModeRestoreTime=255us PortTPowerOnTime=10us
        L1SubCtl1: PCI-PM_L1.2+ PCI-PM_L1.1+ ASPM_L1.2+ ASPM_L1.1+
               T_CommonMode=0us LTR1.2_Threshold=0ns
        L1SubCtl2: T_PwrOn=50us
    Capabilities: [128 v1] Power Budgeting <?>
    Capabilities: [420 v2] Advanced Error Reporting
        UESta:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        UEMsk:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        UESvrt: DLP+ SDES+ TLP- FCP+ CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF+ MalfTLP+ ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        CESta:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- AdvNonFatalErr-
        CEMsk:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- AdvNonFatalErr+
        AERCap: First Error Pointer: 00, ECRCGenCap- ECRCGenEn- ECRCChkCap- ECRCChkEn-
            MultHdrRecCap- MultHdrRecEn- TLPPfxPres- HdrLogCap-
        HeaderLog: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
    Capabilities: [600 v1] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=024 <?>
    Capabilities: [900 v1] Secondary PCI Express
        LnkCtl3: LnkEquIntrruptEn- PerformEqu-
        LaneErrStat: 0
    Capabilities: [bb0 v1] Physical Resizable BAR
        BAR 0: current size: 16MB, supported: 16MB
        BAR 1: current size: 4GB, supported: 64MB 128MB 256MB 512MB 1GB 2GB 4GB
        BAR 3: current size: 32MB, supported: 32MB
    Capabilities: [c1c v1] Physical Layer 16.0 GT/s <?>
    Capabilities: [d00 v1] Lane Margining at the Receiver <?>
    Capabilities: [e00 v1] Data Link Feature <?>
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia```

I think that there is my usb-c adapter in dmesg logs, but I doesn't see any problem here
```[    3.293291] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    3.293293] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[    3.318074] usb 3-4.1: No LPM exit latency info found, disabling LPM.
[    3.343273] usb 3-4.1: New USB device found, idVendor=343c, idProduct=0000, bcdDevice= 0.00
[    3.343276] usb 3-4.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[    3.343277] usb 3-4.1: Product: USB Type-C Digital AV Adapter
[    3.343278] usb 3-4.1: Manufacturer: xxxxxxxx 
[    3.343279] usb 3-4.1: SerialNumber: 000000000000
```  (xxxxxxxx and 000000000000 are real values from log)

I tried a lot of things, prime-select, manually configuring display using xrandr profile

Somebody have any idea? (I can provide more logs if you need)

